# javascript regex Numbers and letters only

Tags: javascript, regex

This should automatically remove characters NOT on my regex, but if I put in the string `asdf sd %$##$`, it doesnt remove anything, and if I put in this `#sdf%#`, it only removes the first character. I'm trying to make it remove any and all instances of those symbols/special characters (anything not on my regex), but its not working all the time. Thanks for any help:

```js
function ohno(){
var pattern = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");
var str = "#sdf%#"; //"asdf sd %$##$" // Try both


str = str.replace(pattern,' ');

document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = str;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the g flag to remove more than one match:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "g");
```

Note that it would be more efficient and readable to use a regex literal instead of the RegExp constructor:

```
var pattern = /[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g;
```

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags)

Answer (score 4):

You need to set global using `"g"`, The flag indicates that the regular expression should be tested against all possible matches in a string.

```
new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "g")
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)

```js
var pattern = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "g");
var str = "#sdf%#"; //"asdf sd %$##$" // Try both


str = str.replace(pattern,' ');
alert(str)
```